# convert negative value to zero in mysql

Tags: mysql

When the value of an unsigned field becomes negative it becomes a very big positive number.
I use a query like this:

```
UPDATE table SET foo=foo+bar
```

I want it to become a zero when it gets negative instead of that.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET foo = GREATEST(foo+bar, 0)
```